# How to draw circle and slanted lines using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, line, drawing

My teacher is teaching us how to draw pictures using Tkinter on Python, but I still need help. I'm new to digital technology, and I'm trying to draw a cone with a scoop of ice-cream. How do I draw a slanted line and circle on Tkinter using this format (example):

> ice_creamTk=drawing.create_line(100,105,200,105,400,105,500,105,700,105,width=4)

The numbers I put in are just examples, I don't actually know what I'm doing.

Comment: To begin with the variable naming is wrong. Then to create circle, you can use `create_circle`

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Thanks, could you please explain which part I named wrong?

Comment: You can't use a hyphen '-' when naming a variable. Instead use an underscore '_'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the shape of an ice-cream cone you need two lines and an arc.

Assuming you have a `root` and a `canvas` defined you can use the following code to make two lines in the shape of an upside-down cone:

```py
canvas.create_line(150,200,75,100, fill="brown",width=2)
canvas.create_line(150,200,225,100, fill="brown",width=2)
```

And to create the arc at the top:

```py
canvas.create_arc(75,175, 225,25, start=0, extent=180, fill="yellow",width=0)
```

The above code will give you the following result:

[image]